# Is there a way to add security header on ORACLE Web Logic without load balancer?

Tags: oracle, security, weblogic, weblogic12c, websecurity

I currently use ORACLE Web Logic without load balancer e.g. nginx or others
I'm not sure is there a way to configure the security header such as XSS protection on ORACLE Web Logic?

Comment: If you can update the source code of the web app you can add a http filter to add any custom header in the response.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin do you have the sample or guideline where I can add the HTTP filter into the source code?

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/filters.htm#WBAPP449) from Oracle about http filters in WebLogic

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Is there a way to fix via ORACLE middleware by configuring?